# tokenUrl in social login (janrain) for x-cart

Tags: token, facebook-social-plugins, janrain, x-cart

I am getting following error while configuring
`social login( Janrain )`
 for x-cart based e-commerce website ( Facebook and Google+)

> The tokenUrl or xdReceiver has not been whitelisted

while the tokenUrl that i have set i.e. `[www.culturetruck.com][1]` is whitelisted. I guess I didn't understand the concept of tokenUrl. Please suggest me what should I use as token URL to receive tokens in X-cart?

Answer (score 2):

1) According to 'Social Login Flow Walkthrough'
http://developers.janrain.com/overview/social-login/social-login-overview/

- Janrain posts an access token to your token URL.
- Using the access token and your API key, your application can fetch
     data about the user through our Social Login REST API.
- User data can be served to your site to customize the end-user
      experience.

2) X-Cart 4 'Social Login' module uses URLs like these 
https://www.culturetruck.com/xauth_return_rpx.php?xid=8bf6ea9554b4b33e4698d0258575d7da
as Token URL.

In this case you have to add these URLs to the whitelist

```
www.culturetruck.com
culturetruck.com
*.culturetruck.com
cdn-social.janrain.com
```

according to 
https://janrain.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203661356-The-definitive-token-URL-or-xdReceiver-has-not-been-whitelisted-error-thread

3)To create an integration from scratch follow this guide
http://developers.janrain.com/overview/social-login/social-sign-in-migration-guide/#Step_3Generate_New_Code

This is about Token URL
http://developers.janrain.com/overview/social-login/implementing-social-login/#4_Create_a_Server-side_Token_URL

Comment: Thanks, I have edited token url And all of urls that you mentioned were already whitelisted, still having same issue, it logins into facebook and google+ but doesn't log into my website. Janrain widget shows tokenurl redirect message but then nothing happens and the login buttons appear again.

Comment: Your 'token url' script should create an X-Cart profile/session in your database. It should acts like modules/XAuth/return.php. The related code is `func_xauth_login($idData['service'], $idData['provider'], $idData['identifier'], $profile, $address, $error)`

Comment: You should be able to see what the token url is that is getting created by X-Cart by using your browser developer tools and tracing the network calls.  You should see the token url getting passed in as a parameter during the initiation of the Janrain Social Login process.

Comment: Thank buddy for a solution. I don't know questioner's issue is solve or not but you solved my issue. Now I have clear flow, need to use "https://www.domainname.com/xauth_return_rpx.php" as tokenUrl when it comes to janrain. Thanks for en lighting the things.